# Why one of the two object instances pointing to the same object behaves differently upon assigning NULL to any of them?

Tags: php, class, object, reference

Consider below code snippet :

```
<?php
  class SimpleClass {
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
      echo $this->var;
    }
  }

  $instance = new SimpleClass();

  $assigned   =  $instance;

  $instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';
  var_dump($instance);
  echo "<br>";
  var_dump($assigned);
?>
```

The output of above code is as below :

```
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) { ["var"]=> string(30) "$assigned will have this value" }
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) { ["var"]=> string(30) "$assigned will have this value" }
```

I understood the above program well. I understood the fact that any changes to either `$instance` or `$assigned` will be reflected in the other, because they are pointing to the same object instance.

But this principle is failing in below code upon assigning `NULL` to any of the two object instances. It is expected that both of the object instances should become `NULL` but one of the two contains `NULL` and other doesn't contain `NULL`. Why so?

```
<?php
  class SimpleClass {
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
      echo $this->var;
    }
  }

  $instance = new SimpleClass();

  $assigned   =  $instance;

  $instance = NULL;
  var_dump($instance);
  echo "<br>";
  var_dump($assigned);
?>
```

Output of above code is as below :

```
NULL
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) { ["var"]=> string(15) "a default value" }
```

Also, in the above code no where the class method `displayVar()` is being called which echoes the text `'a default value'` nor there is any constructor method present then how the `var` property of an object instance `$assigned` is getting set instead of having `NULL` in it?

As both of the object instances are pointing to the same object why they behave in one way when `NULL`is assigned to one of them and other(the expected) way when string or some meaningful value is assigned to one of them?

Comment: By assigning object to variable, it only copy 'memory address' of that object, not whole object with it's content. To copy object with it's content you need to use: $assigned   =  clone $instance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an object, PHP creates a zval under the hood. It's some space in memory holding the object structure and data. Ok, [it's somewhat more complex](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/zvals/memory_management.html), but that's all you need to know for this case.

Assigning the object to `$instance` means you are assigning a pointer sort of thing to this zval. When you then do `$assigned = $instance`, PHP just makes `$assigned` point to this zval, too:

```
$instance -> your object <- $assigned
    ^                           ^
    |____________ = ____________|
```

So you effectively have two separate pointers (indicated by `->` and `<-` above) to the same underlying data structure.

When you assign `NULL` to one of the variables, you are only clearing out the pointer of this particular variable to the zval. But the other variable still points to it:

```
$instance = NULL;

// causes

$instance -> NULL
     ^       your object <- $assigned
     |                          ^
     |___________ != ___________|
```

Let's try this in an interactive session (type `php -a` in your shell):

```
php > $a = new StdClass;
php > $a->foo = 42;
php > $b = $a;
php > var_dump($b);
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(42)
}
php > $a = null;
php > var_dump($b);
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(42)
}
```

This is different from using an actual reference, where `$assigned` actually points to the pointer of `$instance`:

```
your object <- $instance <- $assigned
                   ^            ^
                   |_____= _____|
```

When you set `$instance` to `NULL` here, you are deleting the connection between your object and the `$instance`, so `$assigned` also loses it's (indirect) connection to your object.

```
php > $a = new StdClass;
php > $a->foo = 42;
php > $b = &$a;
php > var_dump($b);
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(42)
}
php > $a = null;
php > var_dump($b);
NULL
```

By doing `$b = &$a;` `$b` doesn't point to the zval directly, but to `$a` actually, hence when you assign `NULL` to `$a`, `$b` will be whatever you assigned `$a` to and vice versa, e.g. if you do `$b = 42` afterwards, `$a` would be 42 as well:

```
$instance = null;
// causes
null <- $instance <- $assigned
            ^            ^
            |_____= _____|
```

So even when you set `$instance = null` you are still maintaining the reference from `$assigned` to `$instance`. To completely delete/unlink the association between `$a` and `$b`, you'd need to use `unset`.

Comment: Thanks for the complete and meaningfully explained answer. By the last sentence "$b will be whatever you assigned $b to" do you mean that after deleting the variable $a, I can assign any value to the variable $b as it has become free/empty/NULL after deleting $a(which was a reference)?

Comment: @user2839497 sorry, I mistyped. Added clarification.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But this one is last doubt from me. By means of "delete $a" are you saying to unset($a) or $a = NULL or something else?

Comment: @user updated again. Hope this clarifies it. I suggest to play around it with the interactive console. You can launch it via `php -a` on the shell.

Comment: @Gordon : Just let me know how to get out/exit from the interactive console? I'm using Command Prompt of Windows 10 Home 64-bit operating system. Thank You.

Comment: @PHPLover you type "exit" into it

Answer (score 4):

`$assigned = $instance` means that you're copying a pointer because whenever you assign a new object to a variable, you're basically making a pointer reference to the object.

So when you do `$instance = NULL` you're assigning null to the $instance variable while `$assigned` still pointing to the object that you created previously

Have a look at this link http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: Look at the first code snippet. In it the change in property value is taking place for both $assigned and $instance. So, they should behave in same way when NULL is assigned to any one of them. Why such difference in behavior is there for different types of values?

Comment: @user2839497 In the first code snippet you're changing the object itself which were referenced by 2 variables `$assigned` and `$instance`. However when you do `$assigned = NULL` you're not making the object become NULL but you're making `$assigned` refers to NULL while the object itself is still safe in the memory

Comment: @user2839497 There’s no difference. In both the variable you assign gets the value. In one it’s `var`, in the other it’s `instance`.